# SOQL UserName and UserRole

Tags: soql, query, nested

Line: 5, Column: 1
System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: User.UserRole

In the debug statement if I add UserRole.DeveloperName i get the above error
How to print UserName and UserRole

```
   List<User> usrlst = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.DeveloperName LIKE : '%CSR%' and IsActive = True];

   for (User u: usrlst)  {
          system.debug ('The CSR name and role:'  + u.Name );
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty straightforward. If you want to reference a field from a queried record, you need to include that field in the `SELECT` clause.

In this case, that means including `UserRole.DeveloperName` in the `SELECT`.